# Decryption of windows files

Tags: php, android, python, windows

Please, i actually encrypted a folder on my initial windows  OS before formating, but unfortunately after backing it up on my Hard drive i forgot to back up the certificate as well. Now after getting a new OS installed, the folder and the content wont copy to the new OS or any other PC, prompting permission not granted. I tried decrypting it from the property tab through the advance and the likes but it wont work. I have checked and search the internet but wont get any solution. I would be very grateful if i can get any help pleases. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: This seems like something more for a windows support forum rather than a programming support site like SO. Also the random tags seem to be completely unrelated.

Comment: If you could decrypt without the key(s) it would be a vulnerability.